# Set timeout for receiving a broadcast

Tags: android, android-intent, timeout, broadcastreceiver

I want to play some sounds via bluetooth and therefore I'm using the audioManager.startBluetoothSco() method. This will (eventually) give out a Broadcast telling me, that everything is ready.
However, if this is not the case, I need a timeout. How do I do that? With SystemClock.sleep? Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a timer. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) is a tutorial for using it.

Comment: Ah, I found the Class "CountDownTimer", that will probably work better then a normal Timer. Thanks!